# Second thread does not run() in for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a test code I have created to study threads. It consist of two threads assigned to the same Runnable. They have to deduct 5 to an int, and stop if the int is not big enough to deduct 5. Thing is, thread 1  "alpha" keeps looping until it is halfway within the loop, in this case being 5. Then thread 2 "beta" starts. It is an extrange behaviour I cannont comprehend. What am I missing?

```
public class synconizedThread implements Runnable {

    int balance = 100;

    public void run() {

        checkAmmount();
    }

    public void checkAmmount() {

        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "checks balance: " + balance);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                withDrawAmmount();

            }
        }

    }

    public void withDrawAmmount() {

        if (balance <= 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Balance is " + balance + " not enough");
        }

        else {
            balance = balance - 5;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "Whitdraws, balance left:  " + balance);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable myJob = new synconizedThread();

        Thread alpha = new Thread(myJob);
        alpha.setName("alpha");
        Thread beta = new Thread(myJob);
        beta.setName("beta");
        alpha.start();
        beta.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're synchronizing the entire loop, so the first thread enters the loop, then won't give up the CPU until after the loop completes.

Instead, you probably want to synchronize **each iteration of the loop**, that way the threads will have a chance to alternate.

You're also synchronizing the call to sleep(), which probably isn't what you want to do. You probably want to move that outside your synchronization.

```
public void checkAmmount() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        synchronized (this) {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "checks balance: " + balance);

            withDrawAmmount();

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues:

- The loop is within the `synchronized` block.  So whoever gets that lock first executes the loop.  Put the `synchronized` inside the loop.  Then a thread will release the lock at the end of an iteration, and compete for it again at the beginning of the next, and you will have concurrency.  For example, make the `withDrawAmount()` method `synchronized`. (If you do that, make sure to move the `println` of thread ID to inside the `withDrawAmount()`.)
- `Thread.sleep()` does not release the lock, so it's not like that fixes the problem of the loop being inside `synchronized`.  You should probably take every `Thread.sleep()` call out altogether since they're just slowing things down.

As ever, you should try to keep the critical section - the piece inside `synchronized` - as small as possible, for maximum concurrency. Synchronizing `withDrawAmount()` should be fine, especially once you get rid of those `sleep()` calls. If you want to have some fun and try to see if you can get even bigger throughput, take a look at [`java.util.conccurent.atomic.AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your first thread enters the synchronized block, loops for 10 iterations and withdraws 5 at each iteration, and then leaves the synchronized block.

So when the 10 iterations are done (and the balance is thus 50), it stops running, leaves the synchronized block, allowing the second thread to run and executes its 10 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `synchronized` keyword. You have it around the whole for loop, so whoever gets to it first gets to run the entire for loop.

Thread B can't access the variable while Thread A is using it - it's locked by A.

If you want both to deduct at the same time you should move the `synchronized` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, your problem is that thread alpha is already halfway through his loop until thread beta starts. 
The synchronized keyword blocks all other thread from accesing the synchronized object. You could put the synchronized keyword inside the loop so that each thread enters and then leaves the monitor each time

ALso, by default, threads do not necessarily get the equal cpu time. So thread alpha starts working as soon as you invoke the start() method and is already halfway through until thread "beta" is even started by the main Thread